# Customize Segment linkTool Handles in JointJs

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, segment, jointjs

I am using Segment linkTool to modify links in my project.

I would like to customize handles's shape using for instance circle or rect, but I am not able to find any access to the toolMarkup.

Any idea how can I modify it in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.